# MySql trigger before update. Перенести значение одного поля в другое, а первое установить в null

Tags: mysql, update, триггер

Мне нужно заполнить поле таблицы Mysql. Напрямую по техническим причинам не получается, поэтому использую временное поле и триггер. Он должен работать таким образом: если временное поле не пустое, то нужно взять значение временного поля и установить его в нужное, а временное поле установить в `NULL`. 
Если делаю так:
Создаю триггер `BEFORE UPDATE`

```
IF NEW.field_tmp IS NOT null  THEN
SET NEW.field_1 = NEW.field_tmp;
SET NEW.field_tmp = null ;
END IF
```

То в таком случае оба поля устанавливаются в `NULL`.
Код ниже работает хорошо, но не обнуляет временное поле.

```
IF NEW.field_tmp IS NOT null  THEN
SET NEW.field_1 = NEW.field_tmp;
END IF
```

Возможно ли эту задачи решить в одном триггере или нужно добавить второй триггер типа `AFTER UPDATE`:

```
IF NEW.field_tmp IS NOT null  THEN
SET NEW.field_tmp = null ;
END IF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать временную переменную `@temp` для хранения промежуточного значения

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tbl_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.field_tmp IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET @temp := NEW.field_tmp;
  SET NEW.field_1 = @temp;
  SET NEW.field_tmp = NULL;
END IF//
```